# Authenticate to JIRA with gmail in python

Tags: python, oauth, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to authenticate to jira by google sign-in using a python script . I am using `jira python` library.

I tried using `basic_auth` but it failed with error as my account is registered through gmail.

```
jira=JIRA(options,basic_auth=(values['USERNAME'],values['PASSWORD']));
```

Comment: What's the error returned?

Comment: it was unable to authenticate the user

Answer (score 5):

When you first logged in as a Google user to the system, you would have been prompted to create an "OnDemand" password, used for things like Subversion or authenticated RSS feed access. This is the password you will need to use when using the JIRA API.

If you can't remember this password, please see: [https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Changing+Your+Password+in+Atlassian+OnDemand](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Manage+your+profile+and+password)

[Source](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/69621/how-to-authenticate-against-the-ondemand-jira-rest-api-by-using-google-account)

Comment: I tried this but I think this work when we have a jira account.